# session start redirect doesent work

Tags: php

I add this code to my php page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header('Location: login.php');
}

?>
```

As I said it`s on top of my page but redirect does not work
I have got a message in browser "we can't reach this page."

Comment: code for one page isn't enough. check for errors in all other pages using sessions.

Comment: there is  a problem with your login.php as the error says.

Comment: do you redirect from subfolder? or do you need to redirect inside a folder? Or do you use any framework(for routing/etc.)?

Comment: Could you add your file structure as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo "Session exist"; exit;
}
else{
echo "No Session Found"; exit;
}
?>
```

This will Verify there is session or not

Comment: show me the code where you start $_SESSION['username'];